# can't display table as wanted without adding column to group by

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT status, user_type
  FROM
  (
select user_type, status 
  FROM transactions where status !=1  AND Update_Date BETWEEN     TO_DATE('2022-01-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')     AND TO_DATE('2022-11-13 23:59:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') 
  )
)
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(*)
  FOR user_type IN (1,2,3,5)
)
ORDER BY status asc;
```

which displays the following table:

| status | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 8 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 13 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I want to display the exact same thing but with TOTAL column , like so:

| status | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 12 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 6 |
| 4 | 13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 13 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

in order for that to happen I need to use count aggregate function. now the thing is that if I do that Im required add a group by statement otherwise I get an error " not a single-group group function " and I dont need that group by, it will just mess around with my query and change the data. what should I do? where should I put it( maybe I put it in the wrong place to begin with..)? but its not quite possible that my placement is wrong. something is wrong with the flow( atleast in my brain ) =p
anyways
thanks and have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `+` operator to add the pivoted columns (using the quoted identifiers since your auto-generated identifiers are numeric):

```sql
SELECT p.*,
       "1" + "2" + "3" + "5" AS Total
FROM   (
  SELECT user_type,
         status 
  FROM   transactions
  WHERE  status !=1
  AND    Update_Date >= DATE '2022-01-01'
  AND    Update_Date <  DATE '2022-11-14' 
) PIVOT (
  COUNT(*)
  FOR user_type IN (1,2,3,5)
) p
ORDER BY status asc;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions ( status, user_type, update_date ) AS
SELECT 0, 1, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4 UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 5, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 8 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 5, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 13 UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 1, DATE '2022-01-01' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1;
```

Outputs:

| STATUS | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 12 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 6 |
| 4 | 13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 13 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KaLX1rFt)

Comment: Thank you! how come I didnt think about it:) cheers